# How do I create a web player for a game engine written in C++?

Tags: c++, browser-based-games, web

[This web player](http://www.playverse.com/Anonplayer/0-a2aadd1b76e14d0e848ea1de18dca4e8) is for the Unreal Development Kit, and works very well without a browser plugin. I'm wondering how it is built.

How do I create a web player for a game engine written in C++?

Comment: The web player you linked seems to be in Adobe Flash, but it should be possible to replicate with JavaScript, WebGL and WebAudio. This question is very broad. Is there a specific concept you're stuck with?

Comment: No it seems that it uses HTML5 see the page source

Comment: Are you sure? I may be wrong, but when I visit the page with a browser that doesn't support Flash, the game doesn't load, but informs me that I need Flash Player.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) can be used to port C++ applications to javascript. It was able [to succesfully make the Unreal 3 engine run in a web browser](http://www.unrealengine.com/html5/).

It works best in browsers which support [asm.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asm.js), an optimization-friendly subset of the Javascript language which can reach performance comparable to native code.

Answer (score 4):

[pepper.js](https://github.com/google/pepper.js) allows you to write C++ code and then deploy directly as:

- Machine code via [PNaCl](http://gonacl.com/) for higher performance, currently only supported by Chrome.
- Javascript via [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) for maximum reach.

From the project page:

> pepper.js is a JavaScript library that enables the compilation of
>   native Pepper applications into JavaScript using Emscripten. This
>   allows the simultaneous deployment of native code on the web both as a
>   Portable Native Client (PNaCl) executable and as JavaScript. Native
>   Pepper applications can now be run in Chrome, Firefox, Internet
>   Explorer, Safari, and more.

*Disclosure: I work on the Chrome team.*